# Using Equality for Map Compare

Tags: c++, stl

I know it is bad practice to use equality instead of equivalence when sorting a map.

```
//Equality
bool isEqual(const A& a1, const A& a2 ) 
{
   return a1 == a2 ;
}
```

However I have a couple of very involved classes that I want to map and I have defined operator== for these classes, but not operator<.

Could anyone give me good reasons not to use operator== for map comparisons? I can not think of a example where it would break down in my class (I can add my class source code if needed)

Also should I just bite the built and write the new operators< :-/ ?

I would do something like this for my map.

```
 std::map<A,B,isEqual> ex1;
```

Also would

```
 ex1.find(A);
```

Now use equality instead of equivalence?

Comment: What you want to achieve? I am unable to understand the requirement.

Comment: @iammilind I Have Two class (Say A and B) that come together to make up new classes (Say C, D, E, F...), but there are a lot of different combinations to do this. I need to make sure I have no duplicates of class type A and B, so I need to find the duplicates and remove them. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Remove them from where? `maps` and `sets` can have no duplicates.

Comment: @juanchopanza the new class C that is a combination of class A and B ( I am not talking about multiple inheritance) are in a vector so there will be duplicates. If I use a map It will use the operator< which is not defined in these classes (unless I used equality) - plus I do not need to map these classes with another object.

Comment: You have to give the map a comparator that implements strict weak ordering, either via a suitable `operator<` or via a functor. If strict weak ordering isn't implemented, the map will be broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `std::map`, `std::set` and their `multi` siblings are sorted structures as per the C++ standard, and equality cannot be used for sorting. On the other hand, strict weak ordering **can** be used to determine equality.

As to why the structures are sorted, the standard requires that insertion and lookup be of logarithmic complexity, which is achievable by using a binary search tree. The only use for an equality comparison in such a structure is to test for the existence of an element.

If you only had equality comparison, then element lookup would have to traverse the structure, making a comparison each time until the element is found, resulting in linear time complexity.

If you did this

```
std::map<A,B,isEqual> ex1;
```

then the map's comparison would not satisfy [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering), so neither the sorting of the map nor the element lookup would work. So iisn't just bad practice, it just doesn't work at all. You have to either implement `operator<` or provide a comparison functor, and which ever one you chose has to implement strict weak ordering. There is simply no way around that.

Comment: @uanchopanza Thanks for your answer very helpful. When you say it won't work do you mean the compiler will complain or the behavior is undefined?

Comment: @MWright the compiler won't complain, and in general when you don't stick to rules set out in the standard, you invoke undefined behaviour.